# How does a query look through a database to find data?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I haven't found many topics on the internet about this question and very curious of how SQL locates data. I understand that SQL writes to 8KB pages, but how does it look through those pages to find data that the query would request. For example...

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, State 
FROM dbo.tblGeneralInfo
WHERE State = 'MI'
```

Let's say this simple query doesn't have any indexes. Now, how does it find the page with `tblGeneralInfo` data?

When it finds that table, how does it look through that data? Does it look across all the column attributes until it finds "State" and then look through the "State" data? Or does it continue looking thorough all the columns till it reaches the table's last column and go back to column "State" and look through every single row in the column? You get where I'm going with this? Thanks!

Comment: You want to read about "indexes" and "query optimization". That will probably answer most of your questions implicitly. How exactly the database management system maintains and uses the tables (not SQL, that is only a passive language) is a question of the storage engine used.

Comment: SQL Server keeps track of which table is stored on which page (the first page of the table, anyway). If you have **no** indexes at all (not even a clustered index), then you have a **heap** (_a steaming pile of ......_) and SQL Server has no other choice than to just fetch one page after another, search for matching rows, and continue on - usually *not* very effective!

Comment: Read this book: "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals"

Comment: Why is this suddenly about SQL Server?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: `tsql` as tag --> synonym for `sql-server` (OK, there's a *tiny* chance it would `sybase` , but that's so tiny, it's neglectable)

Comment: @marc_s: Ah, I missed that. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: [Understanding Pages and Extents](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't indexed it will in your case go to the state column and do a full scan over the column and pull out any record that has MI value in the state column. However this can be very inefficient and it would be best to put an index on the state column assuming you use that column mostly or partly to search on. If it is indexed SQL will be able to go right to the records it needs.

Put it this way, lets say you have a 12 volume set of Encyclopedia Britanica and you need to find which volume and page that has Queen Elizabeth in it. You could wither start with the first volume and look at every single page of the book and then keep going until you find queen Elizabeth I am guessing about 7000+ pages. Or you could grab the index book find where Queen Elizabeth is and go to the exact volume and exact page where she is. Saving you a couple of hours of looking. SQL Server and Indexes, in general, work the same way.